# Fire tab keypress event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to simulate an actual tab key press in JavaScript. I don't want to focus on the next element or anything like that, I just want to make it seem like the tab key has been pressed.

The reason why is because I am building a form JavaScript class where I want to be able to use the enter key just like tab. If someone is using a native BROWSER autocomplete, I need to fire the tab key to capture the selected autocomplete response. If I just move to the next input it won't capture their autocomplete selection and leave the field blank.

Any thoughts?

Comment: >>I don't want to focus on the next element or anything like that

Mhmm, but that happened when I press the Tab key. The next focusable element get the focus.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't think it's possible; an [article about DOM events here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents) ...mentions that firing an event doesn't trigger the default result of the user action, for security reasons; the script should not be able to simulate user interaction directly. You will have to simulate the behavior the keypress causes (such as focus on a field), instead of trying to actually simulate a keypress. You probably won't be able to interact with the browser's native autocomplete functionality, unless the browser explicitly provides a means for you to do so.

**Edit:**

See also: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete] (Autocomplete HTML attribute)

Comment: Dam i need this. i have a simular issue .. http://stackoverflow.com/q/33261996/1356321