# How to simulate a tab keypress with angular

Tags: events, angularjs

I'm interested in doing a very simple auto tabbing function.  I'd like to programmatically press "tab" for the visitor.  I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this in standard JS (ie - not using jQuery's `.trigger()`).

Usage: `<input auto-tab="3">`

```
directive('autoTab', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope: false,
            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                el.bind('keyup', function () {
                    if (el.val().length >= attrs.autoTab) {
                        //document.dispatchEvent();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. Check out [this post](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601593/fire-tab-keypress-event-in-javascript):

> Note that manually firing an event does not generate the default
>   action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a
>   focus event does not cause the element to receive focus (you must use
>   its focus method for that), manually firing a submit event does not
>   submit a form (use the submit method), manually firing a key event
>   does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input, and
>   manually firing a click event on a link does not cause the link to be
>   activated, etc. In the case of UI events, this is important for
>   security reasons, as it prevents scripts from simulating user actions
>   that interact with the browser itself.

You could try a different approach: change your directive so it receives the id of the element that should be focused next:

```
app.directive('autoTabTo', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      el.bind('keyup', function(e) {
        if (this.value.length === this.maxLength) {
          var element = document.getElementById(attrs.autoTabTo);
          if (element)
            element.focus();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" auto-tab-to="input2" maxlength="5"/>
<input type="text" id="input2" auto-tab-to="input1" maxlength="3"/>
```

Working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9blMQDzUceHZZizKxshn?p=preview).

It's not exactly what you want, but I'm afraid it's not possible to do it by simulating a TAB keystroke.

Comment: Shouldn't you use element[0].focus() to remove the jQuery dependency?

Comment: @BrianF You're right. I totally missed it back when I posted the answer. Will fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianF I've just checked it and the code is right: `element` isn't a jQuery object, so calling `.focus()` directly is alright.

Comment: That's what I thought but it doesn't seem to work for me, I get this error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'focus'. Have you tested without jQuery? Any idea what may be wrong on my side?

Comment: @BrianF Are you using jQuery in order to get the element from the DOM? The code above uses `document.getElementById`, not `$()`. In case you are, then you should do `element[0].focus()` as you've mentioned earlier.

Comment: Sorry my scenario is a little different and I was just using the element passed into the link function, just realised now. That's the one that focus doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

i think this one is better no need to mention id for input element

```
app.directive('autoTabTo', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
    el.bind('keyup', function(e) {
       if (this.value.length === this.maxLength) {
                 var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');
                 inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).focus();
        }
      });
    }
   }
}]);
```

Comment: Nice clever bit of code, but still has a jQuery dependency.

The inner part can be rewritten thusly:

`var inputs = elem.closest('form').find(':input'); inputs.eq( inputs.index(elem)+ 1 ).focus();`

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the degree of browser support you need, [dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent) might do the trick for you.