# Simulating keypress events to navigate a website

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, keypress, myo

I'm working with Myo. It's an armband which connects to the computer via Bluetooth. It can detect movement of hand and can detect several gestures, such as 'wave_left' , 'wave_right' , 'fingers_spread', 'fist' mainly. Now I've to write the Javascript so that disabled persons can navigate the website using Myo. To implement this, I want to map some key press events with Myo gestures.

wave_left => <kbd>Tab</kbd>

wave_right => <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

fingers_spread => <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

fist => <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now here's the code:

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stolksdorf/myo.js/master/myo.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stolksdorf/myo.js/master/experimental/myo.experimental.js" ></script>
```

Myo events are handled here like following:

```
var myo = Myo.create(0);

myo.on('arm_recognized', function(){
    console.log('arm found!', this.id);
});
myo.on('arm_lost', function(){
    console.log('arm lost', this.id);
});
myo.on('wave_left', function(){
    console.log('wave Left!');
    // Tab Key Press Event to be Triggered
});
myo.on('wave_right', function(){
    console.log('wave Right!');
    // Shift + Tab key Press Event to be Triggered 
});
myo.on('fingers_spread', function(){
    console.log('spread!');
    // BackSpace key press to be triggered
});
myo.on('fist', function(){
    console.log('fist');
    // Enter key press to be triggered 
});
myo.on('connected', function(){

});
myo.on('bluetooth_strength', function(BTS){
    console.log(width);
});
myo.on('double_tap', function(){
    console.log('double tap') ;
});
myo.on('gyroscope', function(data){

});
```

I've searched internet. For simulating <kbd>Tab</kbd> key press, people suggested to use `$('some_element').next().focus()` , but I want to get the native <kbd>Tab</kbd> key press. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601593/fire-tab-keypress-event-in-javascript) post says it's not possible because of security issue. But the post is from 2009, and html5 has progressed a lot after then. Is it possible now to trigger keypress event of the special keys and get native result? If possible, what should I do?

Comment: You can trigger a *keydown keypress keyup* even, but you cannot force a key to be pressed. So the .focus() is the best solution.

Comment: what to do with `enter` , `backspace` ? Any Idea?

Comment: got any idea ?? @RafafTahsin

Comment: Solved it other way as Myo latest SDK provides the facility to generate native keypress events. This feature is known as 'Myo Keyboard Mapper'. >>> @MahbuburRahman