# Capture keyboard strokes using javascript and replay all of them after a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement where i need to capture all the keys that a user has pressed and replay the same in the browser after a delay.
E.g> if i have 3 text fields in a form, only field-1 will be enabled and focused on page load. Field-1 has a fousout event which will enable field-2, and field-3 after 10 seconds. Now user does the following without looking at the screen.

1. User keys in "XYZ" in field-1.
2. then immediately presses "TAB" key.
3. keys in "123"
4. presses "TAB" key
5. keys in "XYZ123"
6. presses "ENTER" key

all this is done in less than 10 seconds. i have done evt.preventDefault() for TAB and ENTER so that it does not submit the form nor tab away from the document.
 - **How do i simulate the above keystrokes after 10 seconds?**

I would want the results in the same order the user keyed in. i.e.
 - add values "123" to field-2
 - most importantly invoke the *browser TAB key functionality*!
 - add then add values "XYZ123" to field-3 and so..on.

- Is this achievable using javascript? e.g. Store all the keypress events and fire them one by one after 10 seconds?

Comment: If you have a log of which element the keypress occurred in and which keypresses took place you should be able to do this fine

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly I'm not sure if I completely understood your question, but this `vanilla.js` example will output what you've typed if you stop typing for one second:

```js
'use strict';

var logged = [];
var timer;
var timeout = 1000;

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  
  var character = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  logged.push(character);
  
  timer = setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.innerHTML = logged.join('');
  }, timeout);
});
```

```html
Start typing...
```

If nothing else, maybe it gives you an idea of how to solve your problem.

Comment: but how do i simulate the tab event or Shift+tab events? 
Using the same example, i want the cursor to move to the next 'focusable' element after the 1 second timeout. in other words: invoke the browser default 'tab" functionality after 1 second.

Comment: It looks like i cannot simulate the native tab key events using custom scripts due to various security reasons.
[fire-tab-keypress-event-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601593/fire-tab-keypress-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for :[jQuery Key Press Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp)

You want to append the keystrokes to an array and then do whatever you want :)

Also this question may help
[How to find out what character key is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846599/how-to-find-out-what-character-key-is-pressed)