# JavaScript input value changes not taking effect? Calculation field value does not change?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using JavaScript to populate a page which has a calculation field. The calculation field only gets set when I click on the page or tab manually. I don't think JavaScript is populating the fields until I click tab.

I've tried running a method to focus on all the inputs.

```
function PushTab()
{
    //could not get this working as I could not select a input with js and run the trigger function of jq .. mixing js with jquery is bad.
    //$(this).trigger({
    //    type: 'keypress',
    //    which: 9
    //});

    var doc = window.frames['main'].window.frames['content'].document;
    var tabbables = doc.querySelectorAll("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < tabbables.length; i++) {
        tabbables[i].focus();
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me how I could trigger all my JavaScript changes to take affect, something that simulates a users tab or click on page?

---

Edit

How I change the values:

```
function SetElementValue(name, value) {

    var elementType = "input";
    element = GetElement(elementType, name);
    if (element != null) {
        element.value = value;
        return;
    }

function GetElement(type, name) {
    
    var doc = window.frames['main'].window.frames['content'].document;

    if (doc != null) {
        var aTags = doc.getElementsByTagName(type);
        var searchText = name;
        var found;

        for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {

            if (aTags[i].name.trim() == searchText) {
                found = aTags[i];
//alert(found.type);
                return found;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    return found;
   
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "mixing" JS and jQuery; jQ *is* JS.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am sure your right, it was more a comment to myself, was struggling to run jquery on the selected element when selecting it from javascript, the page has does not have id's on the elements, so the way i selected them in the example above, i was not able to run the jquery trigger function.

Comment: Show the code where you populate the page and how you change the values. This 'focus all inputs' code should work, but probably doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: If each input has an onchange function, why not just manually call those functions when the DOM loads?

Comment: @Shilly please see edit

Comment: Just use doc.querySelector('input[name="theInputsName"]') to select the correct input node directly and then change the value. If you have the correct node, it should change automatically.