# what is the key code for shift+tab?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on key mapping. The problem is that when I press the TAB button down it navigates to the next input field.

> TAB has key of 9 and
>   DOWN has key of 40

But, what is the JavaScript key code to go to the previous input field (SHIFT + TAB)?

What I want is to go to next link; what is keycode or code for the previous link?

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever think that google took them here? (like it did me)

Answer (score 206, accepted):

There's no "keycode", it's a [separate property on the event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.shiftKey), like this:

```
if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 9) { 
  //shift was down when tab was pressed
}
```

Comment: what i want is if i click on up key it should go to previously selected tab so please provide some suggestion..
tahnks

Comment: @rajesh - Can you clarify a bit?  Your question asks for they keycode for shift+tab, but you want to detect the up key?

Comment: ya what i want if i click p button it must move to upper field which has a function like shift+tab. Hence the same i want

Comment: @rajesh - Are you using any JavaScript libraries or no? If you're not, this is probably what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702585/simulating-a-tab-keypress-using-javascript

Comment: There IS a keycode for the keydown event - Shift+Tab keyCode=16

Comment: Peter, the keyCode 16 is for the Shift key.

Answer (score 32):

`e.keyCode` has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) for sometime. Use "e.key" [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

**Usage:**

```
e.shiftKey && e.key === 'Tab'
```

**Example:**

```
function clicked(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey && e.key === 'Tab') {
        // Do whatever, like e.target.previousElementSibling.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: best answer. actual working usecase. Especially for angular. if you're using keycodes in these days you're doing it wrong.

Comment: People keep saying that keycode is depreciated, but as of 2021 there's still not enough support for event.key - https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-key

Answer (score 7):

you can use the `event.shiftKey` property for that: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Event/Shiftkeypressed.htm

Answer (score 3):

This way it worked for me
By checking first if one of key is pressed(`tab`/`shift` ) and then check other inside it:

```
if (e.code === "Tab") {
  if (e.shiftKey) {//shift+tab pressed
      //Code
  } else {//only tab pressed
      //Code
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why keeping both conditions in one won't work for me. As good answers are already provided but thought to add this.

Answer (score 0):

in my GWT case

```
if(event.isShiftKeyDown() && event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_TAB){
    //Do Something
}
```