# How to validate Shift+tab Button click in Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Current Scenario is, For a textbox need to verify if Shift+tab is pressed then Js function should return True.
Tried with 
`event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 9` But no luck.

Issue is While pressing Shift+Tab, We do press Shift 1st then Tab in sequence. Thus while pressing Shift (keycode is 16), so this condition is failing. Please help me how to check both key press at a time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the key code for shift+tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044083/what-is-the-key-code-for-shifttab)

Comment: As I have written this is not working for me in the explanation.

Comment: @lokanathdas Then maybe you should include a bit more of your code than just they events. Include the code you have tried. It's not good enough to say "it don't work"

Comment: Hi carsten, as I have explained why this is failing even,  
** We do press Shift 1st then Tab in sequence. Thus while pressing Shift (keycode is 16), so this condition is failing**

Comment: any help can I get on this?