# Trigger Shift and Tab key together

Tags: javascript

I want to test that shift key and tab pressed together takes the user back to the previous text field. I can’t figure out how to trigger shift key and tab together in the test.
Can anyone help?

Comment: The question is how to trigger it not capture

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044102/4185234) answer

> ```
> if(event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 9) { 
>   //shift was down when tab was pressed
> }
> ```

Comment: The question is how to trigger it not capture

Comment: @NoreenAsad https://stackoverflow.com/a/12187302/4185234