# How to differentiate focus in event from TAB and Shift TAB?

Tags: javascript, browser

In a DOM where there is multiple focus elements .
The user can traverse the focus elements using tab , or traverse reverse by using shift + tab.

Listening on the focusin event how can we know whether it was triggered by TAB or Shift TAB ?

```js
document.querySelector('#sample').addEventListener('focusin', function(){

if(isFromTAB){
 // DO traverse
}else{
  // DO different thing
}


});
```

Comment: A [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) has a [shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey) property which tells you if the shift key was pressed or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the key code for shift+tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044083/what-is-the-key-code-for-shifttab)

Comment: I am not looking for keyCode, I would like to find the infromation from event happening after tab in focus event.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [`relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget) property of the event. For a `focusin` event, the `relatedTarget` property identifies the element that lost focus:

```js
document.querySelector('#b').addEventListener('focusin', (e) => {
  if (e.relatedTarget?.id === 'a') {
    console.log('tab');
  } else if (e.relatedTarget?.id === 'c') {
    console.log('shift tab');
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="a">
<input id="b">
<input id="c">
```

Comment: So they have to keep an hard list of tabindex relationships?

Comment: @Kaiido So far have not found anything in the DOM API to retrieve information about the tab order. Do you know of anything short of building the list based on element order and `tabIndex` values?

Comment: @Kaiido Doesn't throw in my version of Chrome, but I'll add some Elvis operators. You meant after `relatedTarget`, right? Not after `e`?

Comment: I can use related target information.
If the relatedTarget is before the current target it is traversing using TAB and the if the relatedTarget is after the current target it is traversing using SHIFT TAB.

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy Exactly, but keep in mind that it gets more complex if you start adding `tabindex` attributes to your `input` elements.

Comment: I am assuming all tabIndex would be 0