# How to Simulate a Keyboard Event in React onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am Currently in process of Developing a on screen handler for my Web application using React and i am facing some problem in creating events for backspace and arrow on screen keys.

I have a layout like this

[image]

I was looking at a coupler of questions which used jquery but i also came across multiple SO questions which said its a bad practise to use jquery with React because of the virtual DOM concept react uses .

[How to trigger backspace on a textfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921111/how-to-trigger-backspace-on-a-textfield)

[How to use JQuery with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-with-reactjs)

How do i simulate the events of backspace and arrow left and right buttons from the onscreen controls using React or pure JS.

**Update**

I donot want to have to trigger the on screen button based on keypress, its the other way around. I want to click the onscreen button which trigger the event for the keyboard press automatically and does the necessary event on input.

Comment: If you are using redux or any other state management system, all you have to do is dispatch an action. If not, you can try to register a keypress event on container and then using refs, call click of that button

Comment: @Rajesh I want it independent of redux just on component level i want this functionality . can you elaborate your comment a bit more

Comment: Idea is to have a unified way to handle stuff. So since you have button clicks, you can trigger of necessary button based on keypress using refs. Somethinhg like `this.refs.button_backspace.click()`

Comment: @Rajesh I think you are getting it a bit wrong, I donot want to have to trigger the on screen button based on keypress, its the other way around. I want to click the onscreen button which trigger the event for the keyboard press automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try to  dispatch a KeyboardEvent with corresponding keycodes for from the onClick handler of each of these buttons. You would find the keycodes here https://keycode.info/

Answer (score -1):

Once you capture the Backspace key click event which you showed on the UI. You can try dispatching an event like this .Try using this code inside your click handler.

```js
// keycode 32 is for space event
// keycode 8 is for backspace event

var backspaceEvnt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown' : {'keyCode': 8, 'which': 8});
var spaceEvnt = new KeyboardEvent('keydown' : {'keyCode': 32, 'which': 32});
document.dispatchEvent(backspaceEvnt);
document.dispatchEvent(spaceEvnt);
```

Comment: FYI that should be two arguments, now a key value pair. `new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'keyCode': 8, 'which': 8})` should work instead.