# Press "Delete" key using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Is there any way in Javascript or jquery using which we can internally click the "Delete" button to delete some text in HTML web pages?
I don't want my users to click the "Delete" button physically but I want to give them interface where when they click I will apply the "Delete" button functionality there.

Comment: Why would you want a user to delete your HTML text?

Comment: you could either clear the contents of an element out with `elem.innerHTML = ''` or using something like `contents.substring(0,contents.length-1)` you could truncate the last character off

Comment: can you provide sample what you want?

Comment: This is the only thing which I want that I want internally do the functionality of Delete button inside a Text Editor that I have, on click on a custom option made by me.

Comment: Perhaps [this article](http://www.dotnetvishal.com/2012/11/replace-selected-text-in-textbox-using.html) could be useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger it using the `keydown` function:

```
$(function(){
    var press = jQuery.Event("keyup");
    press.ctrlKey = false;
    press.which = 46;

    $('#check').keyup(function(e){

        alert(e.which);
    }).trigger(press);
});
```

But this solution does NOT simulate a natural keypress event on the HTML element. This method only triggers the keyup event, it does not replicate the user going into the element and pressing that key. For doing that you can refer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702585/simulating-a-tab-keypress-using-javascript).

But this dispatch event is also not globally supported.

I think applying the functionality of delete button on click of button can fullfill your requirement

Just write `$("input").val("")` on click of button or follow the answer of @haxxton given above, OR [SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jhaRoshan/csaxs7y6/)

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment on the OP.

Assuming your HTML looks something like

```
<p id="deleteMe">This text should be deleted</p>
<button id="deleteButton">DELETE</button
```

**Option 1**

if your intention is to remove the entire text of an element you could use

```
var deleteButton = document.getElementById('deleteButton');
deleteButton.onclick = function(){
    var deleteItem = document.getElementById('deleteMe');
    deleteItem.innerHTML = '';
}
```

**Option 2**

However, if it is your intention to only remove one character per click you could use something like

```
var deleteButton = document.getElementById('deleteButton');
deleteButton.onclick = function(){
    var deleteItem = document.getElementById('deleteMe');
    deleteItem.innerHTML = deleteItem.innerHTML.substring(0, deleteItem.innerHTML.length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please visit : [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

you can use the keycode as 46 insetead of

```
character.charCodeAt(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Call internally to a event is simple with `jQuery`:

```
$('#delete').click(); // call internally to 'Delete' button
```

It launchs the click event which contains your delete functionality.

See a demo more complete: http://jsfiddle.net/581env0c/2/